# Add a city field and state field to a table of zip codes

Tags: python, gis, arcgis

Problem - This is a GIS problem where I have a shapefile of zip codes in the U.S. I am brand new to coding. Using Python, how can I add a city field and state field with the appropriate cities/states for each zip code?

I need to do this with the import arcpy module. This is a personal project of mine and I wanted to see if it was possible.

Attempted solutions - So far, all of the possible solutions include importing another module.

Is this possible? This is my first post, I'm looking forward to learning some Python with you all!

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16158/how-to-add-field-in-attribute-table-using-arcpy).

Comment: Close, but this only specifies how to add a field. In addition to adding fields, I would like to fill in those fields with the appropriate city/state with Python.